# using @ControllerAdvice exception handler as a standalone library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller-advice

I want to create a standalone Spring library that handles standard api exceptions via @ControllerAdvice. My approach is to make it easy to use in different modules without any additional configuration.

There is a code of my exception handler:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiErrorControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ApiErrorException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseTo> handleApiErrorException(ApiErrorException apiError) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new ErrorResponseTo(apiError.getMessage()),
                apiError.getHttpStatus()
        );
    }
}
```

How should I configure my application to make exception handler automatically picked up by Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The **@ControllerAdvice** annotation marks the class as a global exception handler.
- The **@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)** annotation on the **handleApiErrorException** method specifies that this method will handle exceptions of type **ApiErrorException**.
- You can add more **@ExceptionHandler** methods for handling specific exceptions. And you can also add a general **@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)** method to handle all types of Exceptions.
- Ensure that your @ControllerAdvice class is within the package or subpackage that is **scanned** by your Spring application. If it's in a different package, you might need to use the basePackages attribute of @ComponentScan in your main application class @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example"), or specify the package in the @ControllerAdvice annotation.